# Given the sample triangle below and the conditions, find the hypotenuse of the triangle

Tags: trigonometry

Given the sample triangle below and the conditions $b=\frac53$ and $a=16$, find the hypotenuse of the triangle.

[image: right triangle]

Comment: HINT: $c=\sqrt[2]{a^2+b^2}$

Comment: Why do you write $B=5/3$? Is this $b=5/3$? or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

It's a right angled triangle so you can use Pythagorean Theorem.

$$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$$

$$16^2 + 5^2/3^2 = c^2$$

$$256 + 25/9 = c^2$$

$$258 + 7/9 = c^2$$

$$\sqrt{258 + 7/9} = c$$

$$c \approx 16.087$$

Answer (score 0):

We initially use the tan function: $\tan \left( \frac{5}{3} \right) = \frac{b}{a} = \frac{b}{16}$, so $b = 16 \tan(\frac{5}{3})$.

You can then directly apply Pythagoras' Theorem, so: $c^2 = 16^2 + (16 \tan(\frac{5}{3}))^2 = 16^2 (1+ (\tan \left(\frac{5}{3} \right) )^2)$, and then $c = 16 \sqrt{1+ (\tan \left(\frac{5}{3} \right) )^2 )}$.